# Scalable board in Python 3

Tags: python, printing

So, I've been trying to create a board with player input options for rows and columns (lets pretend that they are = 4), but I can't print it like this:

```
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

It just prints like this:

```
['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', '\n', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', '\n','X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', '\n', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', '\n']
```

This is what I have:

```
#inputs
rows = 4
columns = 4

#make board
board = ''
for a in range(rows):
    board = board + 'X '*columns + '\n'

#printing
board = list(board)
print(board)
```

My intention is to be able to replace letters later on, that's why I want to make it a list. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace:

```
print(board)
```

with:

```
print("".join(board))
```

or, as @Martijn Pieters mentions, you can write:

```
print(*board, sep='')
```

Comment: or `print(*board, sep='')`.

Answer (score 0):

You may write something like that:

```
rows = 4
cols = 4

board = [['X' for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]
```

and print it like that:

```
for row in board:
    print(' '.join(row))
```